# Starting firefox with extensions enabled in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working with c# winforms and selenium webdrivers. I want it to make where the firefox drivers start with a extension downloaded called imacros.

I tried this didn't work

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(new File("iMacro.xpi"));
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'File' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\Kody\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AppTrailersMobizen\AppTrailers\Form1.cs 26  38  AppTrailers

Comment: Usually people try something first then ask questions. Not vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to use the Java syntax with C#, probably copying and pasting from some example somewhere. The two APIs, while similar, are not exactly the same, and the language bindings take great pains to seem idiomatic to those languages. In this case, the syntax would look something like this:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AddExtension(@"C:\path\to\extension.xpi");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

I would caution you however against blindly copying the above code without making some effort to understand what it's actually doing under the covers.